# multithread database fetch xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi thank you for the help in advance,

I have looked at some of the posts and I am a bit confused about the multi threading.  It seems that it may be pretty easy, however I am very new to programming so I am still trying to grasp this.

These are two calls to pull data from a database, and they take forever as it is... So I'm thinking about multithreading these until I can learn how to build a core data for this.  Right now i am using sqllite and the database involves 10,000 + recipes...  So not lightning fast like I would like...

Please let me know what you think, and how I can make these happen maybe simultaneously? (If thats even possible)

Thank you in advance.

```
requestCount++;
[[DataPuller sharedDataPuller] getAllDeletedRecipeList];
[DataPuller sharedDataPuller].target = self;


requestCount++;
[[DataPuller sharedDataPuller] getAllRecipesList];
[DataPuller sharedDataPuller].target = self;
```

Comment: Vague answer for a vague question... http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing SQLite, you might want to contemplate using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which (a) gets you out of the weeds of `sqlite3` calls; and (b) offers a `FMDatabaseQueue` which allows you to coordinate queries from multiple queues, so that the data operations don't stumble across each other.

Having said that, you suggest that you're having significant performance issues which you're hoping to solve with a shift to Core Data or going multi-threaded with SQLite. That's unlikely. Poor performance of local database operations is generally more of a matter of your application design (e.g. it's unlikely to be wise to try to retrieve the entire details for all 10,000 recipes ... you probably want to retrieve just the unique identifiers, perhaps only those required for the given screen, and then only retrieve the particulars for a given recipe at a later point as you need that). For local database interaction, you rarely have to contemplate a multithreaded implementation, but rather just design the system to retrieve the least possible information at any given point that you need for the presentation. I personally find that my database-driven apps generally only need to go multithreaded when I'm doing extensive interaction with some remote web service (in which case, it's the retrieval of server data and the parsing of that which goes on the separate thread, not necessarily the database operations themselves).

If you're having performance issues with your recipe app, I'd suggest you submit a far more detailed question, with code samples, that articulates your particular performance problem. And I wouldn't be surprised if multi-threading was not part of the solution. Likely, appropriate use of indexes and a more judicious retrieval of information at any given point might be more critical.

Answer (score 0):

Get records from database in the form of pages; i.e. 20 or 50 recipes per page. Have a look on YouTube app. on iPhone or have a look on my app. [HCCHelper](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hcc-helper/id316131072?mt=8)