# NSTimer in objective c blocking main thread - ipad programming

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ipad, nstimer

I am using `NSTimer` in Objective-C to run a background process periodically (1 min interval) which checks for any unsaved data and submits to database through a web service. This process runs fine without blocking the main application's flow until one particular scenario when the web server was re-started.

When the web server was coming up the background process was trying to connect to the server and just hung up there until the server was fully started and reacheable. When it got hung up it also blocked the main applications flow and freezed the entire screen. When the webserver was fully started the hung up process resumed and the main application also resumed working.

Can anyone please let me know why the main application was intermittently freezed when a background process was hung up.

Following code start the timer

```
- (void) startSync{
    syncTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(syncExtSys:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
}
```

Following method is called every 60 seconds and `saveAgendaToDb` method call calls the web service:

```
- (void) syncExtSys:(NSTimer *) theTimer{
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    AgendaItemViewController *agendaItemViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AgendaItemViewController"];
    RollCallViewController *rollCallViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RollCallViewController"];

    for(int i=0;i<agenda.count;i++){
        unsavedAgenda = [agenda objectAtIndex:i];
        if(unsavedAgenda !=nil && [unsavedAgenda.dirtyFlag isEqualToString:@"Y"] && [self checkNetworkStatus]){

            NSLog(@"agenda out of sync = %@ %@",unsavedAgenda.measureType,unsavedAgenda.measureNum);
            [agendaItemViewController saveAgendaToDb:[agendaItemViewController createDictForAgenda:unsavedAgenda]:unsavedAgenda];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<_rollCall.count;i++){
        Member *member = [_rollCall objectAtIndex:i];

        if(member !=nil && [member.dirtyFlag isEqualToString:@"Y"] && [self checkNetworkStatus]){

            [rollCallViewController saveRollCall:[rollCallViewController createRollCall]];
            break;
        }
    }

    [self calcDirtyFlag];
}
```

Code calling the web service

```
-(void) saveAgendaToDb:(NSMutableDictionary*) agendaDictionary:(AgendaItem*) agenda{
    NSError *error;
    CommVotesAppDelegate *delegate = (CommVotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    @try{

        NSString *postUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@:%@%@%@/%@",@"http://",delegate.prop.serverName,
                                   delegate.prop.port,delegate.prop.urlPattern,delegate.prop.saveAgendaMethod,delegate.prop.objectType];
        NSURL *postUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:postUrlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequestPost = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:postUrl];
        NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:agendaDictionary options:0 error:&error];
        [urlRequestPost setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequestPost setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [urlRequestPost setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [urlRequestPost setHTTPBody: postData];
        // NSLog(@"After calling webservices");
        NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequestPost returningResponse: nil error: &error ];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response after calling save agenda web service = %@",returnString);
       [delegate dirtyFlagCalc:returnString :[error localizedDescription]:agenda];
    }@catch(NSException *nserror){
      NSLog(@"Error while sending agenda through webservices = %@",nserror.debugDescription);
    }@finally {
        NSLog(@"Inside finally block of agenda saving ");
        [delegate saveDataToDisk];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for your background process.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please take a look at the code.

Comment: Show the code for how you are trying to connect to the web service.

Comment: I have edited to show the method which does the webservice call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465496/run-a-process-in-the-background-while-user-can-still-use-the-ui/13465979#13465979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer fires on the main thread. If the syncExtSys: method does not complete promptly it will hang the main thread.

Your situation is that you want to do something that may potentially take awhile but you want the results to be displayed in the UI on the main thread. Some good ways to handle this is to do one of the following with Grand Central Dispatch:

1. Use a timer dispatch source to do the processing on a background queue and then dispatch the results for display on the main queue.
2. Stick with the NSTimer but dispatch anything that may potentially take awhile in syncExtSys: to a background queue and then dispatch the results back to the main queue on completion.
3. Use all non-blocking calls in syncExtSys: and everything that it calls.

Comment: Is there a way get this done without blocking the main thread ?

Comment: I agree with this diagnosis; there's no evidence of any background processing in the posted code. `NSTimer` pumps its events into the current run loop, it doesn't create a new thread.

Comment: I added some suggested approaches. The second one is probably the least code change.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is this call: `sendSynchronousRequest`. That's it in a nutshell. There is just about never *any* reason to send a Web request synchronously - and now you know why you shouldn't do it. It's synchronous! That means it blocks the thread while we wait - if there is a long wait, there is a long block. This is the main thread, so we block the user interface, the timer, everything.

Just switch over to asynchronous request and proper use the delegate callbacks and all will be well.

Comment: In my scenario the call needs to be synchronous since I need a success/failure flag from the webservice to proceed further.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't believe that. Web communication *never* needs to be synchronous. When you use asynchronous Web requests the response comes back through the delegate messages: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html That is the standard architecture and there should be no reason for you not to use it. You need to rearrange your code to fit with the asynchronous architecture.

Comment: OK but what if the flow of the application depends on the response from the webservice. In this case the application has to wait for a response from the service after which it can proceed to the next screen. Can this be accomplished using the delegate call back methods ...?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you have to do. You proceed in stages. The delegate callbacks initiate the next step ("proceed to the next screen"). I repeat - this is what you are supposed to do, and you should do it. Otherwise you are blocking on the main thread which is a disaster for your users (and the device may kill your app abruptly). Don't be lazy; don't be scared; do it right.

Comment: If thats the intended way to do then I'll do it. Thanks for letting me know. I'm still in the learning curve so I'm not lazy and scared. Just wanted to ensure what am doing before even doing it.

Comment: Yes, but I "let you know" with my original answer. And so did my comments, which pointed you to the documentation. And so did the other answer, which you accepted. *Listen* to the answers you are given. Otherwise what's the point of asking?